# What is an example of a mobile app using an eye icon for showing the password in clear text

Tags: password, native-app

I am seeking an example to use in the 2nd Edition of the Mobile Design Pattern Gallery, O'Reilly Media 2014, but I cannot find the example I thought I had on hand. Can you think of any?

Comment: If you can't find even one example then I'm not sure it qualifies as 'a pattern'.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a "mobile app" as such but Windows 8 was designed for use on tablet devices and its lock screen password entry and wi-fi network setup UIs use an eye icon for "Show Password" functionality; I suspect it's standard on Modern UI password fields.

## Lock Screen

[image: Lock Screen Password Entry]